organise files by folder by means of an identifier with a python script
`Hello everyone I have a problem with my python script
I need to organise files that I download in my "Download" directory, I made a script in python, but I need that it organise files by folder but the folder need the name of the file without the extension and if the file has different name each one that a organise in a different folder.
my code is below:
import os
import shutil

# Directorio de origen y destino
directorio_origen = 'C:/Users/DZMD6S0/Downloads'
directorio_destino = input('Elige la dirección donde quieres introducir tus archivos:\n')

# Comprobar si el directorio de destino existe, si no, crearlo
if not os.path.exists(directorio_destino):
    os.makedirs(directorio_destino)

# Obtener la lista de archivos en el directorio de origen
archivos = os.listdir(directorio_origen)

# Obtener los identificadores para organizar los archivos
identificadores = input("Ingrese los identificadores separados por coma: ").split(',')

# Iterar sobre cada archivo
for archivo in archivos:
    # Obtener la extensión del archivo
    nombre, extension = os.path.splitext(archivo)
    # Verificar si la extensión es .inc o .pc
    if extension in ['.inc', '.pc']:
        # Obtener los identificadores del archivo
        partes_nombre = nombre.split('_')
        identificadores_archivo = partes_nombre[:len(identificadores)]
        # Comprobar si los identificadores coinciden
        if identificadores_archivo == identificadores:
            # Crear la ruta completa del directorio de destino
            ruta_carpeta_destino = os.path.join(directorio_destino, '_'.join(identificadores_archivo))
            # Comprobar si la carpeta de destino ya existe, si no, crearla
            if not os.path.exists(ruta_carpeta_destino):
                os.makedirs(ruta_carpeta_destino)
            # Construir la ruta completa del archivo de origen y destino
            ruta_origen = os.path.join(directorio_origen, archivo)
            ruta_destino = os.path.join(ruta_carpeta_destino, archivo)
            # Copiar el archivo al directorio de destino
            shutil.copy2(ruta_origen, ruta_destino)
            print(f"Archivo {archivo} copiado correctamente a {ruta_carpeta_destino}")


